# replace one column with values of another column belonging to two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as below:

```
import pandas as pd

d={'PART_NO': ['J661-03982','661-08913', '922-8972','661-00352','661-06291'], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [541,1273,1110,1575,295]} 

suggest = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and

```
d={'A': [1161,224, 505,1033,812], 'B': [957,417,440,588,910],'C':[392,167,97,70,703],'D':[187,2021,3437,2416,2117],'PART_NO':[541,1273,1110,1575,295]}

result = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to replace the `PART_NO` in the result data frame with `PART_NO` of the suggest data frame. I am doing the following:

```
df4 = result.replace(suggest.set_index('PART_NO_ENCODED').to_dict()['PART_NO'])

df4 = df4[result.isin(suggest['PART_NO_ENCODED'].tolist())]
```

However the problem is this is replacing the values for `PART_NO` but making all the other columns `NaN`. How do I solve this where I want the other column values to remain intact and only the `PART_NO` to be replaced with the `PART_NO` from suggest?

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
d={'A': [1161,224, 505,1033,812], 'B': [957,417,440,588,910],'C':[392,167,97,70,703],'D':[187,2021,3437,2416,2117],'PART_NO':['J661-03982','661-08913', '922-8972','661-00352','661-06291']}

result = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `.map`. You can choose to fill anything that isn't mapped to what it was previously, instead of leaving it as `NaN` if that's your desired behavior.

```
s = suggest.set_index('PART_NO_ENCODED').PART_NO
result['PART_NO'] = result['PART_NO'].map(s)
#result['PART_NO'] = result['PART_NO'].map(s).fillna(result.PART_NO)
```

Output: `result`

```
      A    B    C     D     PART_NO
0  1161  957  392   187  J661-03982
1   224  417  167  2021   661-08913
2   505  440   97  3437    922-8972
3  1033  588   70  2416   661-00352
4   812  910  703  2117   661-06291
```

Comment: Thank You @ALollz... I know what I was missing now.

Answer (score 2):

You can start off by bringing the columns in the same `df` using `pd.merge`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'PART_NO': ['J661-03982', '661-08913', '922-8972', '661-00352',
                 '661-06291'], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [541, 1273, 1110, 1575, 295]}
suggest = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'A': [1161, 224, 505, 1033, 812], 'B': [957, 417, 440, 588, 910], 'C': [392, 167, 97,
                                                                             70, 703], 'D': [187, 2021, 3437, 2416, 2117], 'PART_NO': [541, 1273, 1110, 1575, 295]}
result = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

result['PART_NO_ENCODED'] = result['PART_NO']

df = pd.merge(result, suggest, on=['PART_NO_ENCODED'])
df = df.drop(['PART_NO_ENCODED', 'PART_NO_x'], axis=1).rename(columns={'PART_NO_y': 'PART_NO'})
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C     D     PART_NO
0  1161  957  392   187  J661-03982
1   224  417  167  2021   661-08913
2   505  440   97  3437    922-8972
3  1033  588   70  2416   661-00352
4   812  910  703  2117   661-06291
```

Comment: :No I am looking to replace the values in result PART_NO corresponding to the PART_NO_encoded from the suggest data frame. A merge won't work because it needs to check the value and then replace.

Comment: No this doesn't work as the PART_NO and the PART_NO_Encoded is getting repeated in the final result when I apply to the original set. I do not know why. My solution works in correctly replacing the PART_NO but the only problem is it makes the remaining values NAN. So what I am looking for it how to get around that problem